# Determining the kernel and image of a Linear Map

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, solution-verification

Hello to all math people,

maybe there is someone who could help me with this task?

$V$ is a $K$-vector space and $U$ is a subspace of $V$. The Linear Map to consider is:

$$f : V → V/U, v ↦ v + U$$

**Problem:** Determine the Kernel and Image of this Linear Map.

**Thought on this**: Do I get it right, that $\ker f= U$; because only for $u∈U$ we have $u+U=U = 0$ in $V/U$?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, the kernel is equal to $U$ since $v+U=U$ (which is the zero in $V/U$) if and only if $v\in U$.

Since $V/U$ consist of all cosets $v+U$ with $v\in V$ by definition, the image of $f$ is all of $V/U$.